# Web service reference location?

Tags: .net, web-services, project-structure

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution that's currently consisting of three projects:

1. A DataFactory project for Business Logic/Data Access.
2. A Web project consisting of the actual user interface, pages, controls, etc.
3. A Web.Core project consisting of utility classes, etc.

The application requires consuming a web service. Normally I'd add the service reference to the Web project, but I'm not sure if this is best practice or not.

The following options are open to me:

1. Add the reference to the Web project.
2. Add the reference to the Web.Core project, and create a wrapper method that Web will call to consume the web service.
3. Add a new project called Web.Services, and copy step 2.

This project is expected to increase in size so I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 3. If the function of web service is not wrapped from any of your existing projects.